# Liferay Portal - Disable loading porlets on startup

Tags: liferay, portal

I want to disable loading on start up of all portlets I deployed to the Liferay portal and want to load them on demand i.e., when a request or any dependent portlet is loaded.

How can I do this? Is there any settings available for this?

Thanks.

Comment: I can imagine *what* you want to do, but absolutely not *why*... There's a lot of work that a portal environment does for you - why reinvent the wheel instead of fitting into the environment? Use the time that you won to actually concentrate on adding more business value instead of worrying about infrastructure.

Comment: The purpose is to reduce the liferay server start up time since I have more number of porlets deployed (almost around 100)... This is really making the server start up very slow...